# Android FileNotFound exception while reading content URI

Tags: java, android

I'm sharing a file from one (sender) application to another (receiver)application using the content provider. In the sender application, I have a file stored at internal storage. I'm creating content URI using following code at sender application side:

```
                try {
                        File file = new File(path); //path is file path which is stored in internal storage
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            String uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(DispatcherApp.mContext, AUTHORITY, file).toString();
                            intent.putExtra("uri", uri);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Manifest file provider code at sender end:

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="net.rhei.btchat"
            android:exported="false"
            android:process="@string/process"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />

        </provider>
```

provider_path file  contents:

```
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="share_images"
        path="Android/data/net.rhei.btchat/files/Pictures" />

    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />

    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="/" />

    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="/" />

    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />


    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />

    <files-path
        name="allfiles"
        path="/" />
    <files-path
        name="tmp"
        path="tmp/" />

</paths>
```

with this code I'm getting file uri be like: 
 content://net.rhei.btchat/files/shared/1/1569942820242

At receiver application end I'm reading file contents using the following code:

Manifest file provider code at receiver end:

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.droidipc.androidipcpoc"
            android:exported="false"
            android:process="@string/process"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

Reading file contents using following code:

```
                        Uri mUri = Uri.parse(file_uri); // here I'm getting file_uri = content://net.rhei.btchat/files/shared/1/1569942820242
                        String packageName = "com.droidipc.androidipcpoc";
                        context.grantUriPermission(packageName, mUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        try {
                            InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mUri);
                            is.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(SocketHandler.class.getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

I'm getting FileNotFound exception while opening the input stream using above URI.

Comment: `//path is file path which is stored in internal storage` Please give full path as every body has its own ideas about what internal memory would be. And show your provider_paths.xml file. `String uri = FileProv....`. Also show the value of uri.toString().

Comment: `At receiver application end I'm reading file contents using the following code:` ?? The receiver does not have to declare a fileprovider in its manifest file. Only the provider (which you call sender) has to implement a file provider.

Comment: The provider should transfer the `String uri = FileProvider.getUr...` to the receiver using an ACTION_VIEW intent for instance.

Comment: According to the requirement I have to read the file in my application only for that  I'm using a content provider for creating content URI and sharing that URI with the help of broadcast receiver to another application (Receiver app)

Comment: Please check provider_path.xml file contents:
```

Comment: As long as you think that you need a provider also at receiving end i cannot help you. Further at receiving end you grant a read and write permissino. That is impossible. Only the provider can grant them. We cannot see how those permissions in the intent at provider code reach the receiver.